# How to click first link where id contains certain value

Tags: cypress

How to click first link where `id` contains certain value?

For example:

```html
<a id="mambo" href="#"></a>
<a id="jumbo1" href="#"></a>
<a id="jumbo2" href="#"></a>
<a id="mambo" href="#"></a>
```

I want to click the first link where the `id` contains `jumbo` which would be `jumbo1`. How can I do that in Cypress?

I tried:

```javascript
cy.get('a:visible').contains('jumbo').click()
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cypress uses jQuery selectors

so you can use a [starts-with-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) if you want to match a string that starts with `jumbo`

```js
cy.get(`a:visible[id^="jumbo"]`);
```

or [contains-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) if you want `jumbo` to be anywhere within the id

```js
cy.get(`a:visible[id*="jumbo"]`);
```

Comment: Ahh didn't know I could do that, thanks!!